# Connect Meteor Cordova built app to local server and Database

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

im trying out my first Meteor Cordova app. My Meteor app was standalone and functions fine. Then I added the Cordova part. When I run the app with

> meteor run android-device

everything works fine on my mobile device that is connected via usb cable and I can access my local database that is running on port 3001.
This is where my question comes in , when I try to build the app using

> meteor build buildfolder
> --server=http://127.0.0.1:3000

because that is where my meteor project starts up when I use meteor run, my app cant seem to connect.

I have the code
`Meteor.startup(function () { console.log(__meteor_runtime_config__.ROOT_URL); });`
and on startup on the app it does say it is running on http://127.0.0.1:3000 but after that I keep getting the error GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/sockjs/info?cb=h_i9p49ua9 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have been looking for documentation , but cant find any step by step instructions just to build an apk I can install on my Android device and connect to my local instance of Meteor on my pc as well as the database.

Just to add in my config.xml file i get this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that your app will try to connect to 127.0.0.1, but that's localhost -- it's the phone itself! If you just want to try it locally get the local IP of your server (*other* than localhost/127.0.0.1). This is often `192.168.1.N` for some `N`. Under linux you can use `ip a` to see all your IP addresses for all devices. Find the one for your ethernet or wifi connection (*not* `lo`). Use that IP. Your Android device, assuming it is on the same network, will be able to resolve that and connect to your server.

Comment: Thanks for thr response. I did try doing that. I then run into two problems. 1. My meteor app is running on localhost but if i go to my ip:3000 its not running there , so how will my phone know where the local server is or is it implied that it will just know? 2. When I build the app with my ip i get this in the config.xml file "<access origin="*://localhost" />
    <access origin="*://10.0.2.2" />" . Is there somewhere else where i also have to change the server that the mobile device has tp connect to?

Comment: Thanks your advice worked for the phone and then for the server or meteor side I just ran meteor run --mobile-server http://192.168.1.N .